# How to long press on android record button(during chat) for a particular time duration in appium test, by java

Tags: java, android, appium

How to long press on android record button for a particular time in appium test, by java.
I have tried 2 ways but both are not working at all, those are:

Way 1:

```
By pressRecBtn = By.id("recorderButton");
int x = 353;  // x coordinate of device screen, get it after enabling the Show touch and Pointer location from developer option 
int y = 980; // same as x
int timeInMs = 4000;

Action.longPress(driver.findElement(pressRecBtn)).longPress(x, y, timeInMs).perform();
```

Way 2:

```
By pressRecBtn = By.id("recorderButton");
int timeInMs = 4000;

Action.longPress(driver.findElement(pressRecBtn)).waitAction(timeInMs).perform();
```

for this way its press on rec button but for a default time(>=1000 MS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working cool!!

```
By tapOnRecIcon = By.id("btnRecord");    
int timeInMs = 4000;
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction((MobileDriver) driver);

touchAction.longPress(driver.findElement(pressRecBtn),timeInMs).release().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
 TouchAction Action = new TouchAction(driver);
 Action.longPress(driver.findElement(By.name("xyz"))).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void longClick(String element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));

        TouchAction Action = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
        Action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();
    }
```